# Wordpress printing extra content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code:

```
<div class="post-body">
    <?php $permalink = the_permalink(); the_title( '<h4><a href="' .  $permalink . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h4>' ); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

But when page is loaded, there is an extra text which is link to the post before that heading `h4`. I don't know why is wordpress doing that although it isn't programmed to do so.

Comment: I can't post the image but here is the link: http://imgur.com/AdwKqfC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you says this:

```
$permalink = the_permalink();
```

In wordpress, the `the_` for example `the_permalink()` is not return with the permalink, but echoes it.

You can use `get_permalink()`, if you do not want to print it out.

See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

Comment: fun fact: WP 3.9 introduced `get_the_permalink()`, a wrapper for `get_permalink()`

Comment: Good to learn something in every day. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Thanks bro, it works with `get_permalink`. BTW, @diggy what is a wrapper?

Comment: In the wordpress file, `link_template.php` if you see the `get_the_permalink()` function, then you will see this: `function get_the_permalink( $id = 0, $leavename = false ) {
 return get_permalink( $id, $leavename );
}`

What it is do is just call the `get_permalink` function. So, it is an alias. Do exactly what `get_permalink` just lot of people suffering of lack of this function. WP developers are inconsistence in everything. Most of the the_* has the get_* but not for this. So they add a "wrapper"

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the way you're getting the permalink.

`the_permalink` will output the permalink whereas you need to use a function that just returns it.

Change:

```
$permalink = the_permalink();
```

To:

```
$permalink = get_permalink();
```